# What causes 2007 Outlook to start asking for password when password hasn't been changed?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Upon launching Outlook, I get the Enter Network Password prompt asking for the server, user name and password.  The server and user name are correctly filled out.  I have two PCs configured with this email account, and both display the same error.  I have not recently changed the email credentials on the PCs or remote server.  It just stared happening a couple of hours ago.  Don't know if it is relevant, but my host provider is Comcast.

What might cause this?  Can it be a virus fishing for my password?

Comment: Can you log into your Comcast account via the web?  My first thought was your password expired, but Comcast doesn't expire passwords.  The fact this is showing on two pc's makes it harder to be malware.  I'd navigate to Comcast.net in a browser and attempt logging in, for some reason it seems like your password has already been changed.

Comment: Also what specifically is in the pre filled out server info you mention?

Comment: @Tyson  Server is prefilled as `mail.comcast.net`.  I could log onto xfinity/comcast with  my username/password, but can't access email..

Comment: That's what I thought the outcome of this was going to be.  Make certain to use a completely unique password for your Comcast account because often times your email address is used as a username elsewhere.  Also anyplace else that you were using the same password as the old password, you need to change your password.  Be very careful to never use the actual password to your email for any other account.

Comment: Yea, just was on the line with Comcast (joy...), and had them reset my password.  Can logon to comcast with the new password, but still can't access email either on the comcast website or outlook.  Looks like it is definately comcast related and not outlook.

Comment: Actually I doubt it was a Comcast "thing".  More likely your password was compromised.  Read carefully the suggestions I made in the previous comment.

Comment: But the new totally random password also doesn't allow me to access email, but does allow me to logon to comcast website.  How can that be?

Comment: Restart outlook, I suspect it's gotten confused. If you can log into Comcast.net the password should work for mail servers, unless it's a temp password... In that case you need to change it